# Magento Report Collection notice

Tags: logging, magento

Once in a while I get the following notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index:  title  in /opt/ocentric/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Mysql4/Report/Collection.php on line 126
```

The ugly thing is that it's making the system.log file huge. Once it occurs the notice logging enters in a infinite loop. I can't figure out what triggers it.

Looking through the getIntervals() method it seems that this issue is related to date range filtering in the reports but I can't figure out how `$t` remains unset.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 1.7, the class has been moved, so I'm not sure how much it has changed. Assuming the method structure is pretty much unchanged, the only way `$t['title']` could not be set is if _period is not 'day', 'month' or 'year'. Personally I'd add some debugging code into the class such so that after the switch statement you do something like:

```
if ( ! isset($t['title'])) {
    Mage::log('Period is '.$this->_period);
}
```

The next time the error happens you should hopefully see an unexpected value (it's probably null somehow, leading to an empty string). From there you'll have some better information to debug with. You could also log a debug backtrace, it might be useful.

Comment: already did that :) waiting for the notice to occur. I'm using 1.9 Magento Enterprise

Comment: If you are using Enterprise, don't you have access to technical support?

Comment: Pay attention to the Mage::registry caching, if you play with overriding function getPeriods() and returning an empty array, you can get it cached in the current Magento session and cause you headaches until your session expires or you relogin.